# RestKit requires iOS5.1.1 and above. did it mean that Base SDK can be iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, restkit

uRestKit requires iOS5.1.1 and above. But when my Base SDK is less than ios8, there are something wrong happen in building project. The compiler complains about some macros are not defined.(i.e RK_CALENDAR_IDENTIFIER_GREGORIAN)

Comment: Why is your base SDK less than 8?

Comment: Because my Xcode version is 5, I want to make my app compatible with IOS 6.

Comment: So you'll need to use an older version of RestKit, master head expects up to date tools and SDKs

Comment: Thank you. But it says that RestKit requires IOS5.11 and above in 'README.md' file. So why I need to use older version of RestKit. I also want to make my app compatible  with IOS 9, should I use another version of RestKit . I do not think it is a good way.

Comment: That is the supported runtime version, not the base SDK. that will also change at some point in time... How many of your users are running iOS 5?

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it . About the question, sorry, I am a new person in our company, so I do not know how many users are running iOS 5 now. Our PM just  ask me to make our app compatible with IOS6....